# Can't load an Adobe Captivate HTML5 presentation in a Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, adobe-captivate

I am trying to store an Adobe Captivate HTML5 file in a bucket and then load the file and play the presentation. I've watched other videos on this and many people have successfully used Google Cloud Storage for this purpose, but they generally use it on a public bucket. My bucket is private and only accessible to a couple of users if it matters.

The file I'm trying to load will only go as far as showing a loading icon. Originally it only showed a blank page, and I was advised to add a  tag to the  with the "Authenticated URL" of the file and now it shows a loading icon but still won't load correctly.

Has anyone had this issue with html5 files before? Or know if there is anything in particular you need to do differently to view a file like this on a private bucket with a couple users vs allUsers?

Comment: To move this along, please provide the code you used and the steps you followed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Captivate HTML5 file, is still HTML codes. After you uploaded to the GCS, when you visit GCS bucket, actually you executed [getobject](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object), you downloaded the file to your browser, of course, the browser can write HTML file and display in your browser. Just set it to public to allusers, clean the browser cache. the try to use the public url visit again.